# Parsing dates in pandas.to_datetime when date is 'DD-MMM'

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a column in a pandas dataframe whose entries are dates.

Currently those dates are stored as strings like '05-Aug'.  I would like to convert these to dates.

```
d = {'Date': ['05-Aug', '03-Sep'], 'Status': ['S', 'I']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

gives the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "...\datetimes.py", line 2187, in objects_to_datetime64ns
> values, tz_parsed = conversion.datetime_to_datetime64(data.ravel("K"))
> File "pandas_libs\tslibs\conversion.pyx", line 359, in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.datetime_to_datetime64
> TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>

> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "tmp.py", line 5, in 
> df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

> File "...\datetimes.py", line 887, in to_datetime
> values = convert_listlike(arg._values, format)

> File "...\datetimes.py", line 401, in _convert_listlike_datetimes
> result, tz_parsed = objects_to_datetime64ns(

> File "...\datetimes.py", line 2193, in objects_to_datetime64ns
> raise err

> File "...\datetimes.py", line 2175, in objects_to_datetime64ns

> result, tz_parsed = tslib.array_to_datetime(

> File "pandas_libs\tslib.pyx", line 379, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime

> File "pandas_libs\tslib.pyx", line 606, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime

> File "pandas_libs\tslib.pyx", line 602, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime

> File "pandas_libs\tslib.pyx", line 557, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime

> File "pandas_libs\tslibs\conversion.pyx", line 516, in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.convert_datetime_to_tsobject

> File "pandas_libs\tslibs\np_datetime.pyx", line 120, in pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.check_dts_bounds
> pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-08-05 00:00:00

I've played around with the `format` options, but nothing seems to change the outcome.  What do I need to do to get it to interpret this correctly?

Comment: `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d-%b')` but you're going to get a default year of `1900`. date needs day, month, _and_ year if one is not provided it will use a default.

Comment: Thanks - how would I tell it that it's 2021?

Comment: Add to both your column and your format string `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + '-2021', format='%d-%b-%Y')` or `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + f'-{pd.Timestamp.now().year}', format='%d-%b-%Y')` if you always want the current year.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69553600/10197418